# Python. Suma de dos factoriales

Tags: python, python-3.x

¡Buenas!
Necesito que el usuario introduzca dos números y calcular el factorial de estos dos números ingresado por el usuario. Finalmente sumar el resultado de esos dos números.
Consigo calcular el factorial de cada número introducido por el usuario pero no consigo reflejar la suma entre ellos.
Este es mi código :

```
def factorial(parametr1, parametr2):
    f1 = 1
    for i in range(2, parametr1 + 1):
        f1 = f1 * i
    print(f1)
    

    f2 = 1
    for i in range(2, parametr2 + 1):
        f2 = f2 * i
    print(f2)
    
    return f1, f2

parametr1 = int(input("Introduce el primer número:"))
parametr2 = int(input("Introduce el segundo número:"))
factorial(parametr1, parametr2)
print(f1 + f2)
```

Me sale el siguiente error: [17:0] name 'f1' is not defined y no entiendo porqué si estoy retornando los valores de f1 y f2.
¿Alguien que sepa lo que estoy haciendo mal?
¡Mil gracias!

Comment: Los estas *retornando* si... pero los estás *almacenando* en algún lado?? Un `return` no es un método mágico que te permite sacar variables de un método a otro sin más, debes ***ASIGNARLOS*** igual que asignas las variables dentro de los métodos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es que no recuperas los valores devueltos por factorial. La línea donde invocas la función debería ser así:

```
f1, f2 = factorial(parametr1, parametr2)
```

La función retorna dos valores, debes recibirla en dos variables.

También debes notar que las variables internas a la función desaparecen una vez que la función retorna.

Otra cosa es que puedes simplificar tu código escribiendo una función más simple, que sólo calcule un factorial, quedando el código así:

```
def factorial(n):
    f = 1
    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        f = f * i

    return f

parametr1 = int(input("Introduce el primer número:"))
parametr2 = int(input("Introduce el segundo número:"))
f1 = factorial(parametr1)
print(f"Factorial de {parametr1} = {f1}")
f2 = factorial(parametr2)
print(f"Factorial de {parametr2} = {f2}")
print(f1 + f2)
```

También es bueno separar los cálculos de la E/S. Ese es el motivo para sacar el `print` dentro de `factorial`.

El código produce:

```
Introduce el primer número:4
Introduce el segundo número:5
Factorial de 4 = 24
Factorial de 5 = 120
144
```

Answer (score 1):

obviando si el código hace o no lo que deseas, estas haciendo un print(f1 + f2), pero nunca has definido esos números, están definidos en la declaración de la función, están dentro de la función. Ya que cuando es ejecutada la función las variables desaparecen. Por eso tienes el error.

A parte tienes definido factorial que recoge dos argumentos y al final devuelve 2 valores:

```
def factorial(parametr1, parametr2):
    f1 = 1
    for i in range(2, parametr1 + 1):
        f1 = f1 * i
    print(f1)
    

    f2 = 1
    for i in range(2, parametr2 + 1):
        f2 = f2 * i
    print(f2)
    
    return f1, f2
```

En ningún momento guardas los valores retornados. Prueba a poner lo siguiente:

```
numero1, numero2 = factorial(parametr1, parametr2)
print(numero1 + numero2)
```